# What does "potential divide by zero" mean in Visual C++ C4723 warning description?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

When I compile the following code in Visual C++ 10

```
int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    int len = strlen( "" );
    if( len / 0 ) {
        rand();
    }
}
```

the compiler emits [C4723 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kd039eh.aspx) ***potential divide by zero***.

What does *potential* mean here? My C++ code clearly says "divide `len` by zero", how is the divide *potential*?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kd039eh.aspx

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to devide 0 by 0?

Comment: @ame: the purpose of such questions is not to encourage writing stupid programs, but to learn more about the internals of a particular compiler.

Comment: @arne: I wanted a concise code snippet showing that warning.

Comment: The compiler is not there to babysit you, it does not even need to warn you that what you are doing is incorrect, much less produce a concrete specific error message that fits your exact case. The error message is probably used in other contexts where the compiler cannot guarantee that the divisor will be 0, and at the end of the day, it is pointing you to your problem... so the error message is not *precise*, but is it precise enough for you to detect/fix the issue? what else do you want?

Comment: BTW, strictly speaking, it is only *potential* for two reasons: `_tmain` might never be executed (it isn't the standard entry point), and `strlen` could throw, in which case the division would never be executed.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I see you point, yet I can't imagine such a context where the compiler would evaluate the second operand to be zero at compile time and would be unsure if it was zero.

Comment: @sharptooth: In case the variable is declared `volatile` and initialized to 0, the compiler cannot know whether it is actually zero when evaluated for the second operand.

Comment: @sharptooth: Also, the compiler does not keep track of pointers that might point to this variable through which it might be modified.

Comment: @sharptooth: or the code might be unreachable, or... Just look at it from the opposite side: can you implement a perfect message in all situations? what is the ROI (return of investment) for each hour spent in adding code to provide slightly better error messages? how much maintenance will that code require? At the end of the day, for me as a user, there is no added value in the compiler removing the *potential* from the message, what I want is the compiler to help me detect the issue, and that is done here: the compiler tells me what the problem is. Even "x / 0!!!" is good enough.

Comment: A C program which would actually attempt a division by zero is ill-formed, and the C standard makes no requirement as to what a such program might do before or after such code would execute.  A well-formed C program may, however, include code that would perform a division by zero provided such code is never executed.  The compiler may be able to tell pretty reliably that, if a piece of code were executed, it would cause a division by zero.  It cannot in general, however, determine whether a piece of code would in fact execute.

Answer (score 15):

MSDN article is clear that compiler evaluated operand to be zero already at compile time. So `potential` here means that compiler is unsure about one thing only - whether this code is going to be ever executed or not.

Comment: he will give the same massage even if this is the first line in "main". sure you can say the compiler can't know if you ever going to run the program.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel even if it's the first statement in main(), there's no guarantee the code will run (global static constructor could terminate the process for example). Your compiler actually doesn't even know the entry point of your program.

Comment: @Roee Gavirel So right - computers are not yet sophisticated enough to estimate this kind of probability.

Comment: @Roman even if they were, what would be the point? Having a separate message for a potential runtime error vs. a guaranteed one isn't exactly useful; the code is still wrong, in the same way, regardless.

Comment: Well actually I don't see how this code is wrong. Division by zero? What if this is exactly an intent? Compiler just does what it has to do - it is warning developer that this does not look right and the decision is up to him. The message is chosen this way, the documentation is pretty accurate. We can only tell that the wording 'potential' is somewhat unnecessary, but note that this extra word distinguishes the message from runtime error which indicates that division took place just recently. Potential did not yet happen on the contrary.

Answer (score 4):

It means the same, it's just been polite.
Would you like it to say "You are dividing by zero, idiot !" ? (-`

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't assume the execution path will reach the division by 0.
It's a reasonable assumption, because *execution* of _tmain is decided *after* the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Say you are a compiler developer and you create a static analysis tool to be run during the compilation to help catch errors.

For example, here, a range-based engine that will determine the possible values that the right-hand operator of `/` could take.

Now there are two cases:

- the right-hand side is definitely 0
- the right-hand side is possibly 0

Obviously, separating the two cases requires more effort.

And thus you might rightly assume that the most common cause of errors will be a *possibility* and not a *certainty* (nodoby in its right mind would divide by 0, right ?) and save yourself some work.

- Is it optimal ? For the developer perhaps, for the user not really.
- Is it usable ? Definitely.

Comment: Why no case for the right-hand side is definitely NOT 0 ?

Comment: @Minok: Separating the two cases into three cases requires *even more work* :)